# System requirements : Autocad vs Autocad LT

Tags: autocad

I don't know if LT means Lite version , but i want to know if Autocad LT 2016 , can run better in old PC with less CPU and memory requirements than the Full version of Autocad ?
Actually in the Autocad website , the requirements are exactly the same, so i'm asking if someone have tried working with both versions and may know this.

Thank you !

Comment: Have you searched anything yourself?  We're not here be a G̶o̶o̶g̶l̶e̶ Jon Skeet proxy.

Comment: In the Autocad website , the requirements are exactly the same, so i'm asking if someone have tried working with both versions and may know this.

Comment: Then please include that information in the question.

Comment: @Ferdi You could be the first to try it! I would think that the major requirement would be the capabilities of the version - if you don't need everything that the full version can do and LT is sufficient, then there is no point spending the extra money. Or are you saying that you have the full version and its performance is disappointing?

Comment: If they are both the same, that should answer your question, they will perform relatively the same.  `AutoCAD LT` is 2D drafting  vs `AutoCAD` includes 2d/3d modeling and drafting.  How do I know this?  I did some basic research on the Autocad website.

Comment: @Ramhound I've made this question because i've thought that LT means Lite , so it will require less system resources. The best answer will be from someone that already tried both these. And i have required a possible answer from people that have tried. I've made before the same research that you did on autodesk website.

Comment: From my perspective, since I determine what the difference was, in less then 30 seconds of research you made no attempt to determine what the difference was if you thought it meant "light" ( it doesn't mean that its just a product differentiation between the 3d/2d and 2d product line ).  "The best answer will be from someone that already tried both these." - Great candidate for you to answer your own question.

Comment: @Ramhound I've not tested , so i'm not a candidate to answer.I mean that i've read on autodesk website that the system requirements were the same for both versions.And if the LT has no 3D capabilities , in some point of view seems Lite. But also maybe as it doesn't have 3D , should not require much system resources. But the final word should be from someone that has tested. It seems that you've just read on internet but never tested in work ..

Comment: It does not mean Lite.  The performance of the 2d modeling will be exactly the same.  3D modeling does not exist in the LT version thus cannot be compared.  **You should test both and report back, this type of question, isn't going to be well received**

Comment: @Ramhound if everyone will follow your logic , no question is a good question , because there's always a static answer : "Search on google , test it by yourself , and report back".  But a forum is to share opinions and experiences with each other.

Comment: @Ferdi - We are not a forum to share our opinions.  How a program will function depends on your hardware.  I provided an answer despite by concerns with it.  *I am sure I will live to regret that decision.*

Answer (score 1):

> Can (Autocad 2016 LT) run better in old PC with less CPU and memory
>   requirements than the Full version of Autocad?

`Autocad 2016 LT` and `Autocad 2016` will perform identically when dealing with the same 2d model.

How do I know this:  20 years of experience plus the fact the difference between the two products is that `Autocad 2016 LT` is missing some key features.

[AutoCAD LT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD#AutoCAD_LT)

> AutoCAD LT is the lower cost version of AutoCAD, with reduced
>   capabilities, first released in November 1993. Autodesk developed
>   AutoCAD LT to have an entry-level CAD package to compete in the lower
>   price level. AutoCAD LT, priced at $495, became the first AutoCAD
>   product priced below $1000. It is sold directly by Autodesk and can
>   also be purchased at computer stores (unlike the full version of
>   AutoCAD, which must be purchased from official Autodesk dealers).
>
> As of the 2011 release the AutoCAD LT MSRP has risen to $1200. While
>   there are hundreds of small differences between the full AutoCAD
>   package and AutoCAD LT, there are a few recognized major
>   differences[14] in the software's features:
>
> 1. 3D Capabilities: AutoCAD LT lacks the ability to create, visualize and render 3D models as well as 3D printing.
> 2. Network Licensing: AutoCAD LT cannot be used on multiple machines over a network.
> 3. Customization: AutoCAD LT does not support customization with LISP, ARX, and VBA.
> 4. Management and automation capabilities with Sheet Set Manager and Action Recorder.
> 5. CAD standards management tools.

Here is a shortlist of additional differences:

[image]

Comment: Basically the product isn't a Lite version.  There is a difference between a Lite and entry-level in the software world. Its a full product that has the same 2d modeling features as Autodesk itself ( outside of the features that doesn't have which for the most part have no relation to actual 2d modeling performance ).